# Radio button check on case insensitive match

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a radio button which contains values as `a`,`b`,`c`,`d` . Now I am trying to check only that radio button `Regardless of Case sensitivity` whose value mataches to `var correct` which contains values such as `A`,`B`,`C`,`D` . Kindly let me know how to do that with javascript/jquery? I tried something like following but it didnot work.

```
$("#radio" + correcto).prop("checked", true);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you intentionally using an ID selector to access your radio buttons? I don't think that is really what you want. Try one of these:

```
$(':radio[value=' + correct.toLowerCase() + ']').prop('checked', true)
```

or

```
$(':radio').each(function() {
    $(this).prop('checked', $(this).val() === correct.toLowerCase());
})
```